# Java Object Mapping on Neo4j in play framework using restapifacade

Tags: java, playframework, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

There is a `Country` class:

```
public class Country { 
    public int id;  
    public String name;
    public String locale;
}
```

I have to insert into neo4j.

What I am doing:

```
public void insert(Country country) {
        engine.query("create (n:Country {name:'"+country.name+"',id:"+country.id+",locale:'"+country.locale+"'})",null);
}
```

But I want to put Object directly to neo4j with label.

I am using play framework 2.3.7 with java 1.8 and libraryDependencies are

```
"org.neo4j" % "neo4j-rest-graphdb" % "2.0.1",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-server" % "1.7",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.7",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-json" % "1.7",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spring-data-neo4j](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/) for your requirement.Detailed steps are

1.Add dependencies to build.sbt

```
      "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "3.2.2.RELEASE",
      "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "3.2.2.RELEASE",
      "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-tx" % "3.2.2.RELEASE"
```

2. Global.java

   ```
   public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
       private ApplicationContext ctx;

       @Override
       public void onStart(Application app) {
           ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Neo4jConfig.class);
       }

       @Override
       public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) {
           return ctx.getBean(clazz);
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop(Application app){
           ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)ctx).close();
       }
   ```

   }
3. Configuration class for Neo4j connectivity

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

         public Neo4jConfig() {
             setBasePackage("model");// My Entity package
         }     
      @Bean
      public SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService() {      
           return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
     }   
     @Override
     @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
     public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(getGraphDatabaseService()).getObject();
     }    
   }
   ```
4. Annotate your country class with NodeEntity

   ```
   @NodeEntity
   public class Country{ 
       public int id;  
       public String name;
       public String locale;
   }
   ```
5. Use Neo4jTemplate for saving object to Graph DB

   ```
   @Autowired
   Neo4jTemplate template;

   public Country save(Country country){
       return template.save(country);
   }
   ```